# Windows machines don't work on network, Macs/iOS/Android etc. fine

Tags: windows, networking, mac, router, dhcp

My small network has wires and wifi. I am experiencing problems with almost all my Win 10 machines, which are able to DHCP themselves addresses, but not subsequently communicate with the gateway/dns server. All other machines -- Macs, iphones, androids, work fine.

On some of the Windows machines, a VM running Linux over a bridged adapter also works, so it's not the hardware.

Packet traces on a Windows machine say packets are leaving, but captures on the gateway/router/dns server (its own linux machine) don't show them arriving, except for the DHCP exchange.

Occasionally, for no apparent reason, a Win machine will start working for a while, then fail after a reboot.

All the while, all the other devices are happily working away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Much more information is required.

Comment: What kind of more information will help?   The network is 192.168/16, with the router and DNS on 192.168.0.1.    There are wired connections through switches that don't work, and wireless connections that also don't work from some windows machines.

Comment: What is your router and its OS? What is the error and does it arrive on wired? Are there useful messages in the Event Viewer? Does ping work? Give examples of IP addresses; Do the computers see each other on the network? Are the Windows 10 computers fully patched? Do they use Microsoft accounts or local ones? Do you use Homegroup? That sort of information, the more the better.

Comment: The router is a PC w/2 nics running OpenSuse.    Ping from patched windows hosts -claims- to be successful, but packet traces show arrival at the router, and no reply sent, and traces at the windows machine don't see icmp coming back (!?).   nslookup times out, and tcp connections fail.  There is a mix of local and microsoft accounts, no homegroup involved.    Router is 192.168.0.1 on 255.255.0.0 network.   Machines are DHCP assigned in 192.168.0.[100-250].